# Need to Replace Element value with Mix Content with lxml etree Python

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have an string containing xml structure. `<root><test1>Test 1</test1><test2>Test <dummy>2</dummy> Test</test2><test3>Test 3</test3></root>`, now i want to replace values in element `<test2>` with a mixed content `This is a New Input Scenario <AnyElement>Text</AnyElement> Check`

Below is my code

```
from lxml import etree as ET

source = "<root><test1>Test 1</test1><test2>Test <dummy>2</dummy> Test</test2><test3>Test 3</test3></root>"
repl = "This is a New Input Scenario <AnyElement>Text</AnyElement> Check"

inp = ET.fromstring(source)

for inputelement in inp.xpath('.//test2'):
    inputelement.text = repl

inp = str(bytearray(ET.tostring(inp)).decode())
print(inp)
```

**Output**

`<root><test1>Test 1</test1><test2>This is a New Input Scenario &lt;AnyElement&gt;Text&lt;/AnyElement&gt; Check<dummy>2</dummy> Test</test2><test3>Test 3</test3></root>`

**Expected Output**

`<root><test1>Test 1</test1><test2>This is a New Input Scenario <AnyElement>Text</AnyElement> Check</test2><test3>Test 3</test3></root>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's possible using combination of adding new elements and their `text` / `tail` properties:

```
from lxml import etree as ET

source = "<root><test1>Test 1</test1><test2>Test <dummy>2</dummy> Test</test2><test3>Test 3</test3></root>"

# split mixed content into parts: text / element / text
repl1 = "This is a New Input Scenario "
repl2 = '<AnyElement>Text</AnyElement>'
repl3 = ' Check'

inp = ET.fromstring(source)

for inputelement in inp.xpath('.//test2'):
    # first attach text
    inputelement.text = repl1
    # create new element and attach final part to its tail
    anyelement = ET.XML(repl2)
    anyelement.tail = repl3
    # replace original dummy element with new one
    inputelement.replace(inputelement.find('dummy'), anyelement)
    

inp = str(bytearray(ET.tostring(inp)).decode())
print(inp)
```

Comment: This is correct for current scenario, but what if Mix content has multiple nesting itself. actually i am working on paragaraph, and that will contain multiple list and table inside and need to insert all at once.